# Shopware6 - updating entities - product prices depends on rule builder

Tags: shopware

I have a product that have different prices depends on customer group ( via rule bilder).
Problem is that I can update only main price and updating prices by ruleId is not working.
Here are my two different ways to update/upsert a prices (I am using "prices"  or "ListingPrices" ) :

```
$productRepository->upsert(
[
  [
    'id' => '7d9727a2eec0499eb4b24383cb4e3211',
    'prices' => [
      [
        'id' => '7d9727a2eec0499eb4b24383cb4e3211',
        'ruleId' => 'a397ba8ef07e4dd5a6de50dcb34484dc',//rule id for CUSTOMER GROUP XYZ
        'quantityStart' => 1,
        'quantityEnd' => null,
        'extensions' => [],
        'price' => [
          'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
          'net' => 666,
          'gross' => 666,
          'linked' => true,
          'extensions' => []
        ]
      ],
    ],
    'listingPrices' => [
      [
        'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
        'ruleId' => 'a397ba8ef07e4dd5a6de50dcb34484dc',
        'from' => [
          'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
          'net' => 666,
          'gross' => 666,
          'linked' => 1,
          'listPrice' => null,
          'extensions' => []
        ],
        'to' => [
          'currencyId' => 'b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca',
          'net' => 666,
          'gross' => 666,
          'linked' => 1,
          'listPrice' => null,
          'extensions' => []
        ],
        'extensions' => []
      ]
    ]
  ],
],
\Shopware\Core\Framework\Context::createDefaultContext()
```

);

**EDIT:**

How I can REMOVE all prices and just add new again.
when I want to make :

```
      $productRepository->update(
        [[  'id' => '7d9727a2eec0499eb4b24383cb4e3211', 'prices' => [] ]]
```

response is succefull but, it do not remove a prices of product.

I think removing all and insert again  is faster/easier than searching a id of price and update every price via id.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get any exception etc.?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you should use **prices** instead of **listingPrice** und use **price** for main price.

```
[
    [
        'id' => 'prd_id',
        'price' => [
            [
                'currencyId' => 'currencyId',
                'gross' => 'grossPrice',
                'net' => 'netPrice,
                'linked' => true/false
            
            ]
        ],
        'prices' => [
             [
                'id' => 'price_id',
                'ruleId' => 'rule_id',
                'quantityStart' => 1,
                'quantityEnd' => 10,
                'price' => [
                    [
                        'currencyId' => 'currencyId',
                        'gross' => 'grossPrice',
                        'net' => 'netPrice',
                        'linked' => true/false
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Hey!!
thanks for help guys! 
@Hüseyin Akturan -> you help me find a bug,

in section  prices =>  'price' => [[]]  data must be wrapped in double quotes .

thank you!